# TypeError on simple count command

Tags: javascript, zapier

New to javascript and could really use help.  I'm using the follwing code:

```
// Define "LineItemsIds" in input data section.
// Get the number of line items.
**return** *{ line_items_count: inputData.LineItemsIDs.split(',').length };*
```

I'm getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

I've attached a picture as well -- I'm using Zapier.

[image]

Comment: dont know about zapier but from javascript perspective the error is saying inputData doesnot have `LineItemsIDs` key present or is undefined i.e `inputData.LineItemsIDs` is undefined.

Comment: maybe try `lineItemsIDs` (since the image has an input defined with a lower-case L)

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot your input data is called `lineItemIds` with but you are reading `LineItemsIDs` with capital `L`.

Try changing the code to `lineItemsIds`

```
// Define "LineItemsIds" in input data section.
// Get the number of line items.
**return** *{ line_items_count: inputData.lineItemsIDs.split(',').length };*
```

or the inputData to `LineItemsIds`